# How to create AI with arduino using PHP and Arduino IDE?

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I've created an website, and a **Voice recognition robot using Arduino**, and also a **database** in **mySQL**, named as ***meanings_db*** which consists all the meaning of words. Now what I want is

- when user gives command to arduino voice recognizer for ex: *what is the meaning of beautiful*, and after that,
- arduino should send an **query** to web database asking for meaning of beautiful and when it gets,
- it should speak the meaning of beautiful i.e. *a object which looks attractive*.

Is this possible? If, yes how can I do it?

Comment: What parts of the solution are ready? Where do you stuck?

Comment: I'm not able to understand how to send query to my database i.e. meanings_db and how to get the request back from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `HTTP GET` request from your Arduino to your website i.e.: `http://yourwebsite.com/meaning.php?word=beautiful`. Then your php script will access the `DB` and prints out the result which can be access on your Arduino as the `HTTP Response`. More info about making HTTP requests: [link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient).